# Are higher-resolution images always better?

Tags: image, screen-resolution, image-format

I have had this perception that for a given size, higher resolution pictures will always *look* better than the lower ones.

But on [this link in StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371044/what-resolution-should-my-iphone-app-icon-be) I read something different.

So my questions :

1. For a fixed size will higher resolution images always look better ?
2. Does this improvement, if at all, depend on the kind of display and underlying hardware etc (for example is this above case specific for Apple)
3. Should I always try getting better resolution images?  Or is there a limit after which human eyes will not really be able to differentiate this improvement because of resolution change ?

PS: I am not taking about the print qualities of these images, but the visual experience one gets from seeing them on screen.

---

I will clarify more.

I have to use an image of size 800x600px(Fixed).

I have 3 options : 900 dpi Image, 600 dpi image, 4oo dpi image, all in size 800x600px.

Is it always a good idea to use 900 dpi above 600 and 400 ?

And above stated questions follows with this data.

Comment: It's not immediately clear what you are asking here, the link you provide refers to icons for Apple devices. But I get the impression you are speaking here of general images.

Comment: Yes Daniel, I am asking in general. I have asked in point 2 of my question whether this phenomenon is only for Apple products or any general display ? And hence the link.

Comment: This part doesn't really make sense: "I have 3 options : 900 dpi Image, 600 dpi image, 4oo dpi image, all in size 800x600px"; if they all have the same pixel dimensions, then an image with more dots-per-inch is not *higher resolution* but rather *smaller physical size*. For example, at 900 dots per inch, 800x600px is less than one inch square.

Comment: This question might be better suited for graphic design SE?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Completely ignore DPI settings in your image software. It has no bearing on web graphics.

All that matters is pixel dimensions. A 100px x 100px image at 300dpi is the exact same image on screen as a 100px x 100px image at 100dpi.

DPI only comes into play when you're talking about print graphics.

Where you may want to consider a larger image on the web, however, is with retina graphics. Again, DPI is irrelevant, but the key is that you double the pixel dimensions. So you'd have a 100x100 image for regular browsers and 200x200 for retina.

Answer (score 7):

1. Depends on the PPI (Pixels Per Inch) of the screen. High
   resolution icons will not look any different on a low density screen
   than a low resolution icon.
2. It all depends on the underlying hardware. Pouring rocket fuel
   into your car doesn't turn it into a rocket ship.
3. You should provide images that will suite the screen properties
   of the devices you suspect the application to be run on.

Answer (score 7):

**In digital media, you can't really separate pixels from density (DPI).**

That's because *one pixel is one dot*.

so, if your picture is 400 DPI, and it's 800 pixels wide, it means it's two inches.

Unfortunately, you can't define the DPI of a device (it's a given), it's somewhere between 326 (iPhone 5) and 100 (average LCD laptop monitor).

The Retina Macbook Pro has about 220 DPI resolution, and honestly, I can't really differentiate it from a standard Macbook standing next to it, albeit Apple claims it's better. Perhaps my eyes are getting weary.

But the real takeaway is: in digital media, **DPI can't be set in photoshop, it's the property of the device**.

So:

1. grab some mobile phones
2. look up their screen resolution (eg. 1136x640 for iPhone 5)
3. decide how much screen estate you want to occupy relative to the size of the device (100% = full screen width, 50% = half screen, etc)
4. Multiply resolution with screen real estate (so, 568x640 if you want to occupy half of an iPhone 5's screen)
5. Do this for multiple devices and try to find 2-3 good average sizes.

Or, in case you come from vector graphics:

1. grab some mobile phones
2. look up their PPI
3. export your image according to their PPI (but don't set physical size, let the application calculate that)

Comment: _DPI can't be set in photoshop, it's the property of the device._ I cant comment on Photoshop, but see [this for GIMP](http://docs.gimp.org/2.6/en/gimp-pimping.html#gimp-prefs-new-image). Why is there an option to specify PPI along with width and height then ?

Comment: It's for printing, not for display on screen.

Comment: "one pixel is one dot"  God I wish that were true.  And I personally am astonished by the DPI on the Retina Macbook.  It was night and day for me, but I'm a video/photo guy so I'm a snob about that kind of thing.

Comment: It's mostly a 1to1 relation but on retina, 1px is not necessarily one device pixel. For example, on a retina device, 1px in CSS is actually 4px on the screen itself.

Comment: n support of Aadaam (@amitTomar) DPI is a FLAG which is set by software (including Photoshop). But please realize that DPI is a derived number based upon the number of pixels in the image divided by the number of inches of the desired rendered image. The inches value is unknown. However, I think AAdaam is still confusing things a little. When making a raster image, DPI does not exist except as a mental check to ensure your are providing enough detail for the intended purpose.

Comment: @DA01: let's not confuse the CSS unit of pixel (which is different on a retina solely based on a decision of Apple, it's nowhere standardized, it's a hack to allow easy transition), with an actual pixel (which is for _picture element_, that means, an atomic point of a display).

Comment: @horatio: I hope I don't confuse anything, DPI does exists, at least, it really did matter in cartography where I gained some of my UX knowledge. Simply the pixel density varies from device to device since the 90s, it's only that the retina is a huge leap.

Comment: DA01 and I are both graphic designers so I think we have a decent handle on it. To clarify: I don't think you are confused, only that your explanation is confusing. It seems to me that you are pretty clear on the concept. The confusion most people have is that at the time of raster image creation, inches just don't exist. DPI is a flag or suggestion which has absolutely no bearing on the notation or storage of the "actual" image data and can be altered without adjusting, adding or removing pixels.

Comment: @Aadaam but even the W3C spec points out that pixels are not literal. It *is* confusing, I admit. ;) We can even confuse it further by debating DPI vs. PPI. ;)

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with images, it's always best to take the responsive approach. That is, serve up the image at the best possible fit for the device of the viewer.

It's all about load times here, a large image may take less than a second to load on a desktop with todays broadband speeds, but try to load that on a Mobile device using only 3G and you'll be lucky if the browser doesn't time out.

Break down your image into 3 or four different resolutions, one for each of the following:

- Desktop (Large browser > 960px)
- Desktop (Small browser window < 960px)
- Tablet
- Mobile

Remember to compress your images (as far as you're happy in terms of quality) as much as possible to reduce file sizes and therefore load times.

Comment: Daniel, Image size is constant for my use case. I am just concerned about using an image with better Dots Per Inch.

Comment: @AmitTomar you have no control over dots-per-inch online. You can't change the dpi of a user's screen.

Answer (score 0):

There's no added benefit to downloading an image with a higher DPI than your highest supported screen DPI. At that point you are downloading larger images than you need. Scaling distortion and anti-aliasing could even hurt the quality o the image in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

In order to mitigate the differences in pixel size, Apple introduced the concept of 'points' as a measure of size across different iOS devices. There's a pretty clear explanation in the iOS developer library:

> In iOS, all coordinate values and distances are specified using
>   floating-point values in units referred to as points. The measurable
>   size of a point varies from device to device and is largely
>   irrelevant. The main thing to understand about points is that they
>   provide a fixed frame of reference for drawing.

[Read more here.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW15)

What it comes down to is that if you produce artwork with a resolution of 2 pixels per point, you should be safe, even for retina displays. iPhones have a size of 320x 480 points and iPads have a size of 768x1024 points.